# HTML elements are continuously "nesting" within one or the other

Tags: html, css, templates, nested, blogger

I have my personal style blog at blogger.com platform at http://fashionsanja.blogspot.rs and I'm average good at coding. I have a huge problem with my blog posts, as you can clearly see by visiting it via the link above. In the *blogger help forum* I got the problem "name" and temporary solution, but not a complete answer. The problem is that my **HTML elements are continuously "nesting" within one or the other as each blog posts is displayed**. I'm not expert enough in HTML to solve this alone, I need your help.

I will quote you the reply I got from the Google help forum:

> Your custom Blogger template is pretty much unique due to your custom
>   implementation. The reasons are, at Homepage/index pages, you are
>   allowing your Post HTML elements to display itself inside another Post
>   HTML -- we call it "nesting".
>
> When this happens, it is pretty hard to add & target specific CSS
>   rules as your post HTML elements is continuosly "nesting" within one
>   or the orther as each Posts is displayed.
>
> Below is a temporary workaround until you find (and fix) your Post
>   display "nesting" issues.
>
> Go to Theme > Customize > Advanced > Add CSS ....
>
> .post .post-outer {    margin-bottom: 45px; }
>
> Click Apply to Blog
>
> Again, if you have trouble with coding, I strongly suggest for your to
>   send in your coding issues at stackoverflow.com or Blogger Developer
>   Group where experts there can further assist you. The above could
>   start your conversations there.
>
> Custom Blogger themes to your extent is not supported in Blogger Help
>   forums due to errors and unknown implementations -- even though you
>   are using any default Blogger themes.
>
> This is because we do not have a clue on how you customized your theme
>   as it shows why it is quite difficult to add CSS to re-style your post
>   elements according to your preference.

Comment: So other than the fact the pictures are way too large and the posts are off center, I can't see a true issue. Also, they say in the post that it is a custom template, did you create it?

Comment: But what was the problem. I cant see what is wrong with the blog

Comment: The problem is how to set that all posts show equal, if you check you can see that the newest post, the first one is ok, the second post (labels) is too close to the previous post's footer, and the last post's labels are almost merged to the previous post's footer. Is there a way to fix that and to increase the space between my posts? And it's a custom blogger template, I didn't create it, just modificated it.

Comment: It looks like each of your tags <div class='post hentry uncustomized-post-template' itemprop='blogPost' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'> do not have corresponding closing tags. (</div>). This could be due to another tag above or below this one being left open...

Comment: @Sanja If you add padding-top or margin-top to the center element, it should accomplish exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Jonathan Chaplin Thanks! Only 1 question - is the center element for example post-title, labels, ..? And should try with various values?

Comment: "center" is the element which contains "span" with class "post-labels."

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Theme** > **Customize** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS**

```
.post-labels {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
}
.post-footer-line {
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.post-header { 
   margin: 0 0 0 0; 
}
```

Click Apply to Blog

Comment: Thank you very much, @Bassam That partially solved the issue. Now the only problem is how to make the same with the dates in my post title? Again, in the first post the date is ok, but in second and every after it, they somehow move a bit down, ...

Comment: P.s. I solved it! If someone has the same issue, just put the code like this and that will solve it! ;) Thanks again, Bassam, for your help! :)                                                                                    
  .post-header {
  margin: 0 0 0px 0;
}

Comment: You are welcome, Glad to hear from you and I will update my answer.